# Как мне правильно сделать выборку из MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!
у меня есть три таблицы!

**news**

```
id|title|text|test|qwer|trrr 

1|test name|description|wer234|qqq  
2|test nam2|description|wer234|qqq  
3|test na3|description|wer234|qqq  
4|test n4|description|wer234|qqq  
5|test 5|description|wer234|qqq
```

**type**

```
id|type

1|type1  
2|type2  
3|type3  
4|type4  
5|type5
```

**newsandtyp**

```
 news_id|type_id  

  1|2   
  1|5   
  1|1  
  2|3   
  2|4    
  5|5  
  5|2  
  5|3
```

таблица `newsandtype` это связь многие-ко-многим, связь `news` и `type`
так вот, как мне правильно сделать выборку записей из таблицы `news` учитывая таблицу `type`?
Например хочу вывести:

```
1 test name description type2,type5,type1 wer234  
2 test nam2 description type3,type4 wer234  
5 test 5 description type5,type2,type3 wer234
```

вывести данные таблицы `news` + данные таблицы `type` только если есть связи в таблице `newsandtype`

Comment: *только если есть связи* - `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам потребуется построить запрос с использованием JOIN, схема запроса указана ниже на рис.1:

[image: рис.1 операция пересечения]

Для этого выполним операцию пересечения INNER JOIN. Вывод записей из таблицы news будет зависить от таблицы newsrandtype, а сама таблица newsrandtype будет пересекаться с таблицей type. Зеленая зона на схеме обозначает операцию INNER JOIN.

Вот такой запрос выведет все данные, но здесь могут повторяться новости в зависимости от количества типов, но это можно обработать на серверной стороне.

```
SELECT `news`.*,
       `type`.*
FROM `news`
JOIN `newsandtype` ON `newsandtype`.news_id = `news`.id
JOIN `type` ON `type`.id = `newsandtype`.type_id;
```

В другом случае, можно сделать группировку и вывести типы через запятую в поле types:

```
SELECT `news`.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(`type`.`type`) types
FROM `news`
JOIN `newsandtype` ON `newsandtype`.news_id = `news`.id
JOIN `type` ON `type`.id = `newsandtype`.type_id
GROUP BY `news`.id;
```

Comment: спасибо) помогли